# Postgresql get average period from a table with different partners and purchase days

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, date-arithmetic

So basically I have a table where are partners and the dates when then they did their orders.

| partner_id | order_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 |
| 1 | 2022-01-20 |
| 2 | 2022-02-20 |
| 4 | 2022-01-15 |
| 4 | 2022-01-17 |
| 4 | 2022-01-30 |

And I want to have an information of each partner average of purchase period, e.g.

| partner_id | period |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 |

How do I get these:
1 ID partner -  (2022-01-20 - 2022-01-02)
2 ID partner - 0
3 ID partner - avg(2022-01-15 - 2022-01-17) + (2022-01-17 - 2022-01-30)))

Would it be possible and how to get these intervals?

Comment: Seems that is not needed to divide the date difference by 2 in your explanatory formula.

Comment: My bad, thanks for notification! Will adjust question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to get the previous date, then aggregate:

```
select partner_id,
    avg(order_date - lag_order_date) as avg_date_diff
from (
    select p.*, 
       lag(order_date) over(partition by partner_id order by order_date) lag_order_date
    from partners p
) p
group by partner_id
```

Note that `lag()` returns `null` when there is no previous row, which `avg()` then ignores; this seems to be what you want.

Comment: A more optimal solution, just could need a round and coalesce functions to get exactly the expected result.